# Use http-proxy-middleware with express to access a protected resource

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware

I'm attempting to proxy a remote, protected resource.

The proxy doesn't work, so I'm guessing that I have not configured it correctly.

`server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
    
app.use('/api/employees', 
    createProxyMiddleware(
        {
            target: `https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/${process.env.BAMBOOHR_API_SUBDOMAIN}/v1/employees/directory`,
            changeOrigin: true,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from(process.env.BAMBOOHR_API_KEY + ":password").toString('base64')
            },
            logger: console,
        }
    )
);
    
app.listen(3030, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('Service running');
});
```

When I try to contact the local URL, I get a 404 error:

> No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:3030/api/employees

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Adding `secure: true` had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the `target` to reference the common base of the API and add a `pathRewrite` to remove `/api/bamboohr`:

```
app.use('/api/bamboohr', createProxyMiddleware({
    target: `https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/${process.env.BAMBOOHR_API_SUBDOMAIN}/v1`,
    changeOrigin: true,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from(process.env.BAMBOOHR_API_KEY + ":password").toString('base64')
    },
    pathRewrite: {
        [`^/api/bamboohr`]: '',
    },
}));
```

This allows me to map `http://localhost:3000/api/bamboohr --> https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/{subdomain}/v1`

Without the `pathRewrite` entry, attempting to contact `http://localhost:3000/api/bamboohr/employee/directory` would result in `https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/{subdomain}/v1/api/gateway.php/subdomain/v1/api/bamboohr/employees/directory`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine except I would pass `secure: true` to the createProxyMiddleware config since the external resource is `HTTPS`.